# Python Selenium - How to select a tab in a page

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, selenium-webdriver

The following image is the code of tabs present in a web page:
[image]
The tab names are `Overview`, `Information`, and `Audit` (Kindly refer the top most part of the image).

When I click the tab using mouse the tab is opening as expected, but when I try using selenium python it is not working. The following is the code that I have tried to select the `Information` tab:

Try 1:

```
temp = '//*[@id="RULE_KEY"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]'
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, temp)[0].click()
```

Output:

```
ElementNotInteractableException
```

Try 2:

```
temp = '/html/body/div[3]/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span/div/span[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]'
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, temp)[0].click()
```

Output:

```
IndexError
```

Can anyone please help to select the `Information` tab?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more information of the HTML that you are trying to interact with?

Comment: I have attached the image of the html. Is there anything specific that you need other than that? @AngYC

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if can be shareable in public?

Comment: Hi @Jeril, it seems to be that the HTML that you have provided might be the tab content instead of the tab button (There's a `<i>` icon tag in the HTML but no icon in the tab button). Maybe you can try focus on the "Information" tab button above and check the full HTML of that part?

Comment: @Shawn Actually its an internal application, it does not have access to internet.

Comment: Ok share the HTML in the form of text, sharing HTML in the form of image is a bad idea.

Comment: @AngYC The `<i>` tag is as follows: `<i class="icon icon-openclose"></i>` there is nothing inside it.

Comment: @Shawn When I try to see the page source, i am not able to see any relavent data. Only using inspect we are able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Inspect and try to locate element. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> on the browser --> press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> --> Paste this XPath expression `//*[text()='Information']`. If it locates one element, carry on to below step
2. Check for presence of IFRAME, if no IFRAME is present carry on to next step. If there is an IFRAME you need to switch into it first, below is the code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# below line switches into the IFRAME
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "<xpath of iframe>")))
```

3. Apply waits before clicking button, try below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Information']"))).click()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

4. Try performing `click()` using JavaScript.

Try this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='RULE_KEY'']/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]"))
```

Or this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Information']"))
```

Comment: When i search for `//*[text()='Information']` it shows 5 matches. The following is the element: `<h2><i class="icon icon-openclose"></i>Information</h2>`

Comment: Ok good. Change it to `//h2[text()='Information']` and see if it locates just 1 element?

Comment: It locates only 1 with `//h2[text()='Information']` when i search in the inspect. But `browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Information']")` this returns an empty array in the code

Comment: Try the trouble shooting step in my answer. It's likely that there is either an `iframe` or you need to apply `selenium waits` before trying to do `find_elements`

Comment: Tried bro, timeout error. Thank you for your kind help.